# chart.js plotting timeseries

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Attempting to pass through data from django to a webpage to render a responsive chart. The data are being passed correctly to js, but I am driving myself crazy trying to understand why charts.js is throwing an error.

I have hardcoded some data for example:

```
function setLineChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext('2d');
    var dat_1 = {
        label: 'things',
        borderColor: 'blue',
        data: [
            {t: new Date("04/01/2020"), y: 310},
            {t: new Date("04/02/2020"), y: 315},
            {t: new Date("04/03/2020"), y: 320},
            ]
    };
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [dat_1]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    },
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
            }]
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```
<canvas id="myLineChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

And this returns a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined` error that I can't debug. `setLineChart()` gets called as part of an ajax response on a form update. When I comment out the `options` section, it does render a chart, but misses off the last data point, and has `undefined` as the x-axis marker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js internally uses Moment.js for the functionality of the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This will solve your problem as the following amended code snippet illustrates.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext('2d');
var dat_1 = {
  label: 'things',
  borderColor: 'blue',
  data: [
    { t: new Date("04/01/2020"), y: 310 },
    { t: new Date("04/02/2020"), y: 315 },
    { t: new Date("04/03/2020"), y: 320 },
  ]
};
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [dat_1]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myLineChart" height="90"></canvas>
```